# does we have any code coverage tool for XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

any tools that can tell me what percentage of a `XSL` document get actually executed during tests?

Comment: If your XSLT 2 or 3 processor is Saxon 9 then check http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/performanceanalysis.html which shows some way to get a profile.

Comment: Have a look at the Oxygen XSLT debugger and profiler: https://www.oxygenxml.com/events/2013/webinar_xslt_development_with_oXygen_Part3.html